# Google marker cluster when same lat long address

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps, laravel

More than one marker on same place problem.

I am using MarkerClusterer. When I have two or more markers on the exact same spot, The API only displays 1 marker - the top one. But somehow I want to show all the markers as each one will be opening distinct popup. I have searched found few solutions but none are seem to be working Anybody had similar issue and would plus share a solution?

Comment: `found few solutions but none are seem to be working` - which solutions don't work? Don't want to post one that you've already tried

Comment: If they have the *exact* same `LatLong`, you should consider changing one of them *a bit*. Other option is to have a single pin (with an icon that indicates it has more than a single location - UI) and if a user clicks on it you can use `InfoWindow` and display information.